# Write a program in Visual Foxpro to check a number for perfect square

Tags: visual-foxpro, perfect-square

Ask the user to input a number. Check whether the entered number is a perfect square. I tried.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4fWb.png)

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem. Is it?

Comment: Yes. I tried it. It is issuing a nesting error

Comment: The rules for this site say: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local num, nSqrt
Input "Enter a number" to num
IF m.num > 0 
  nSqrt = SQRT(m.num)
  IF m.nSqrt == INT(m.nSqrt)
    ? LTRIM(STR(m.num)) + ' is a perfect square'
  ENDIF
endif
```